# Lines on screen

Tags: display, hardware-failure

Yesterday I cleaned the dust of my computer with a compressed air machine, the computer worked normally for two hours, but then the screen filled with lines and I cant see anything.

It is not a virus, because I cant see the Intel logo when turning on my computer.

I tried with 2 screens but the problem persists.

What could be the problem, the graphics card or the motherboard? and how can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: Most likely, you've blown an internal cable loose.  Open up your computer and reseat any loose cables.

Comment: grafics card, probably memory specific.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the video card has an issue, however if you have been cleaning the internals, then it is likely the card is not seated correctly and vibration has brought it out of the slot a little.

Open up the case, take out the card, check the contacts on the card and slot for dust or other particulates, then put it back in, pushing firmly and checking visually that it is in place.

Leave the case open initially, and when you turn it on, check that the fan on the card is spinning.